# Is it possible to Update/Save new Record on databaseA on ServerA when databaseB on ServerB is updated?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have this requirement that i need to Update/Save all records from DatabaseA on ServerA  when DatabaseB on ServerB Status is updated to FG-FRESH.

Example:

ServerB| DatabaseB

SerialNumber Status
0000001      Completed
0000002      FG-FRESH
0000003      FG-FRESH

ServerA | DatabaseA

SerialNumber Status
0000002      FG-FRESH
0000003      FG-FRESH

So if SerialNumber 0000001 is Updated to FG-FRESH on ServerB it will also be inserted to ServerA |DatabaseA just clicking a refresh Button.

I will create the application using winform in c#.

Is it Possible? I really need your Help..Thanks in Regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500346.aspx). This is the feature that allows changes on one database to be propagated to a different database. There are various flavors of replication ([Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx), [Transactional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx), [Peer-to-Peer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx) etc). Which is the right one depends on many factors, see [Selecting the Appropriate Type of Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> So if SerialNumber 0000001 is Updated to FG-FRESH on ServerB it will also be inserted to ServerA |DatabaseA just clicking a refresh Button.

so you want this to happen in response to a button being clicked?

Comment: Replication, triggers, or sync framework are all great if you want this to happen automatically (usually what you want).  But if you really want this to happen on a button click, then write a query in the button click event handler which queries for records with the serial number and status "FG-FRESH" and then write code to connect to the other DB and insert them there.  Are you asking about the details about how to write that code?

Answer (score 0):

maybe an SQL trigger is what you're looking for

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247679/sql-server-trigger-insert-values-from-new-row-into-another-table)

When an insert or update happens on a table in one database, you can update another table in another database with the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Sync Framework. Set up the synchronization as unidirectional and use the click on the button as the trigger.