# Request with While in SQL Server does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artfacture 
(
     N int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
     Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     Ht Numeric NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Artfacture (N, Code, Ht) 
VALUES ('1', '1', '10'), ('1', '2', '20'),('1', '3', '30');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Facture 
(
     N int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
     Ht Numeric NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Facture (N, Ht) 
VALUES ('1', '60');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Article 
(
     Code varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     Famille varchar(50) NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Article (Code, Famille) 
VALUES ('1', 'F1'), ('2', 'F2'), ('3', 'F3');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Farticle 
(
     Designation varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     Compte varchar(50) NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Farticle (Designation, Compte)  
VALUES ('F1', '700000'), ('F2', '710000'), ('F3', '720000');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ecritures 
(
     Compte varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     Ht numeric NOT NULL  
)
```

My request is a trigger where adding some new rows in Table Facture, it must add rows in Ecritures with the same numbers of rows of Artfacture

```
declare @piece as nvarchar(50), @code as nvarchar(50)
declare @rowCount int = 0, @currentRow int = 1
select @rowCount = count(*) from ArtFacture where N = @piece;

while (@currentRow <= @rowCount)
begin
    set @Code = (select code from ArtFacture where N = @piece)
    set @compte = (select Compte from Farticle where Designation = (select Famille from Article where code = @code))
    set @Ht = (select ht from ArtFacture where N = @piece)

    insert into Ecritures (Compte,Ht)
    values (@compte,@Ht)
end
```

I have a mistake but I do not know where?

Comment: you declare `@piece` to be `nvarchar(50)` and you never assign it a value.. so your `SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*)FROM ArtFacture where N=@piece;` returns 0 every time i'm guessing. and your while statement will never be true as 1 is never less than or equal to 0

Comment: @DaleK how to do it ?

Comment: even i assign @piece, it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Server trigger insert values from new row into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247679/sql-server-trigger-insert-values-from-new-row-into-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

You're making the classic mistake of trying to write procedural T-SQL instead of set-based T-SQL which SQL Server is optimised for.

If I follow your logic then the following `insert` removes the need for a `while` loop:

```
insert into Ecritures (Compte, Ht)
select F.Compte, AF.Ht
from Artfracture AF
inner join Article A on A.Code = AF.Code
inner join Farticle F on F.Designation = A.Famille
where N = @piece;
```

And if you don't want duplicates add a `group by`:

```
insert into Ecritures (Compte, Ht)
select F.Compte, AF.Ht
from Artfracture AF
inner join Article A on A.Code = AF.Code
inner join Farticle F on F.Designation = A.Famille
where N = @piece
group by F.Compte, AF.Ht;
```

Comment: Thank you, it work but when i have tested and assign same "famille" to 2 "articles", he count is the sum of the 2 "ht", A1 with F1 and A2 with F1 again.

Comment: Are you saying you are getting duplicate rows in Ecritures  and you don't want them?

Comment: Sample  data and expected results would make clear exactly what you are asking.